# How to keep libs out of mangling with UglifyJs or Terser Webpack Plugin?

Tags: webpack, minify, uglifyjs

Mangling my code with terser-webpack-plugin only works until I am setting mangle.properties to true. I need to mangle the properties too, but if I turn it on all kinds of problems related to the used libs occur. So I'd like to keep the lib-sources (inside node_modules) out of the minifying/mangling flow.

I'm using babel to transpile everything to es5 from es6 and higher. I'm using webpack 4 btw.

Looks like the problem I'm facing is that all minifying in webpack only works on the final output javascript instead of the source files.

I tried putting classnames of the libs inside the reserved array inside mangle options, but so far that didn't help. I also tried to work the other way around; use a regex on the terserplugin to only use the plugin for the most important object to minify and mangle, but that's not working as expected, probably because of the babel transpiling. And not what I'm after. I want to minify/mangle at least all of the code I own and prefer the libs to minify too, but without mangle.

I was using uglifyjs-webpack-plugin and uglifyjs-3-webpack-plugin before, but switched to terser-webpack-plugin now because that seems to be more future proof and has more support. So it would be preferred if anybody knows a solution for this on the terser-webpack-plugin (which has practically the same config/api as uglifgyjs). But I'm open to answers for the other plugins as well and might switch back if that works.

I'm trying to get this to work for days now and was digging through all (!) settings of the terserplugin to look for what I need, but couldn't find it. Hopefully anybody here could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @mrT, did you solve this problem in the meantime? I would be very interested in the solution.

Comment: Same question here...!

Comment: Terser maintainer here. Not going to add an answer since this looks like pretty advanced webpack stuff, but you will want to use the `regex` option to make it safer. I'm changing the documentation of this feature to include some advice on how to make it safer (one of those is to avoid using module bundlers), and this doc will be available at https://github.com/terser-js/terser#cli-mangling-property-names---mangle-props when I'm satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I didn't know how to do it but I found out.

According to the terser-webpack-plugin documentation, you can use a `test` to choose which files to minify, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

So you want to add 2 `new TerserPlugin(...)`, one with a test for the files you do want to mangle properties (and mangle properties enabled in the options) and another for the files where you don't want to mangle properties (and mangle properties disabled).